# Changing background images automatically by using css3

Tags: html, css, delay, css-animations

I am trying to change background images automatically by using css3. I have 9 images to change in background. The problem I am facing is, it displays only first and last image in sliding but not the 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. I have following code:

```
<img id="img1" src="images/1.gif">
<img id="img2" src="images/2.gif">
<img id="img3" src="images/3.gif">
<img id="img4" src="images/4.gif">

<img id="img5" src="images/5.gif">
<img id="img6" src="images/6.gif">
<img id="img7" src="images/7.gif">
<img id="img8" src="images/8.gif">

<img id="img9" src="images/9.gif">
```

and here is the CSS:

```
#img1, #img2, #img3, #img4, #img5, #img6, #img7, #img8, #img9 {
    width:610px;
    height:610px;
    position:scroll;
    z-index:-1;
    animation-name: test;
    animation-duration: 90s;
    opacity:0;
}
#img2 {
animation-delay:10s;
-webkit-animation-delay:10s
}
#img3 {
    animation-delay:20s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:20s
}
#img4 {
    animation-delay:30s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:30s
}

#img5 {
    animation-delay:40s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:40s
}
#img6 {
    animation-delay:50s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:50s
}
#img7 {
    animation-delay:60s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:60s
}

#img8 {
    animation-delay:70s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:70s
}
#img9 {
    animation-delay:80s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:80s
}

@-webkit-keyframes test {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes test {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The time of delay for each slide from 1 to 8 is 10s except image9, which has delay time 8.60s.

Please help where I am going wrong. :(

Comment: You need to change the delays for 2-9 to `(n-1)*10`, meaning 2=10, 3=20, etc... If they all have the same delay they will all show at once (the delays don't add onto each other)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay I have made a JS Fiddle, and I think i've come up with what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/d48vdxmv/2/

Basically, you need to wrap your images in a container first:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg">
    <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_02.jpg">
    <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_03.jpg">
    <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_04.jpg">
</div>
```

Then in the CSS, set the container to be relative position, and the images to be absolute so they stack ontop of each other.

```
#container {
  position:relative;
  height:610px;
  width:610px;
}
#container img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

Then add your keyframes, with the different browser variations

```
@-webkit-keyframes imgFade {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes imgFade {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes imgFade {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@keyframes imgFade {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}
```

Then your animation details for all browsers

```
#container img {
  -webkit-animation-name: imgFade;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;

  -moz-animation-name: imgFade;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-duration: 8s;

  -o-animation-name: imgFade;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-duration: 8s;

  animation-name: imgFade;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}
```

And finally your duration times for each image

```
#container img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
#container img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
#container img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
#container img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first statement is semi incorrect. All of them except *the first* are all delayed and not run through immediately, not the last

Comment: Yeah I realised that when I was reading through my answer, then edited it, and read your comment! Thanks for noticing though

Comment: This wont work as expected. The animation duration is `10s` and looped `infinite`. The first image will therefore start the animation again, just as the 2nd image start, and both of those will restart at the same time as the 3rd, and so on.

Comment: So, the `animation-duration` should be 90s?

Comment: Well. The animation keyframes OP posted have `opacity: 0` from `0%` to `100%`, if you didn't notice. But changing the duration to `90s` would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: I have edited the code as suggested by the answers and comments. I have now a new type of error. :( Please see the editing details.

Comment: I have edited the the CSS3 as was suggested by the answer. Now the problem is, first image delays for 10 secs, when second image appears, the first image doesn't disappear. Same way, when third image appears, first and second images do not disappear. First block of CSS is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Lee :) and all. :) The solution provided in answer and the ideas presented by others work perfectly. Made my day. :)